# Maildev crashes with "Socket closed unexpectedly" error in docker container after first call

Tags: docker-compose, nodemailer, next-auth

Maildev crashes with "Socket closed unexpectedly" error in Node.js application
I am encountering an issue with my Node.js application where I use Maildev as my email server. The application crashes with the following error message:

```bash
/home/node/lib/mailserver.js:267
  } else throw err
         ^

Error: Socket closed unexpectedly
    at TLSSocket.onError (/home/node/node_modules/smtp-server/lib/smtp-server.js:473:29)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:629:26)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:526:35)
    at node:net:323:12
    at Socket.done (node:_tls_wrap:588:7)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:629:26)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:514:28)
    at TCP.<anonymous> (node:net:323:12)
```

I am using NextAuth for authentication and have configured an EmailProvider. Here is my configuration in the NextAuth config:

```js
...
EmailProvider({
  server: {
    host: process.env.EMAIL_SERVER_HOST,
    port: process.env.EMAIL_SERVER_PORT,
    auth: {
      user: process.env.EMAIL_SERVER_USER,
      pass: process.env.EMAIL_SERVER_PASSWORD,
    },
    tls: { rejectUnauthorized: false },
    secure: false,
  },
}),
...
```

I also have a docker-compose.yml file where I define the Maildev service. I have made sure that the environment variables are correctly set.

I'm not sure why I am encountering this "Socket closed unexpectedly" error. Can someone please help me troubleshoot this issue and provide guidance on how to resolve it?

docker-compose.yml:

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  maildev:
    image: maildev/maildev
    restart: always
    environment:
      - TZ=Europe/Berlin
      - MAILDEV_WEB_PORT=1080
      - MAILDEV_SMTP_PORT=1025
      - MAILDEV_INCOMING_USER=username
      - MAILDEV_INCOMING_PASS=password
      - MAILDEV_INCOMING_SECURE=false
      - MAILDEV_HTTPS=false
    ports:
      - "8080:1080"
      - "8025:1025"
    logging:
      driver: "json-file"
      options:
        max-size: "1m"
```